# Header not showing with createBottomTabNavigator - React NAtive

Tags: react-native, react-navigation

I am creating a very simple tab navigation with two screens. I want to show a header on top of each screen. I am running the following code, but I don't see any header. The header just does not appear.

I am using react-navigation@3.11.1, I tried reverting back to 3.10.0 and even 3.0.0 and still don't see the headers. So I am assuming it's not a bug in react-navigation.

**Update: This is the expected behavior. See: https://github.com/react-navigation/react-navigation/issues/6149**

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import { View, Text } from 'react-native';
import {  createAppContainer, createBottomTabNavigator } from 'react-navigation';

class MusicScreen extends Component {
  static navigationOptions = {
    title: 'Musiiic',
  };
  render() {
    return (
        <View >
            <Text>Music Screen</Text>
        </View>
    );
  }
}

class MoviesScreen extends Component {
  static navigationOptions = {
    headerTitle: 'Movies',
  };
  render() {
    return (
    <View>
        <Text>Movies Screen</Text>
    </View>
    );
  }
}

const MainNavigation = createBottomTabNavigator({
    Music : {
      screen: MusicScreen,
      navigationOptions: ({navigation}) => ({
        title: 'Music',
        headerTitle: <Text>MUSIICCCC</Text>,
      })
    },
    Movies : {
      screen: MoviesScreen,
      navigationOptions: {
        title: 'Movies',
      },
    },
  },
  {
    headerMode: 'screen',
    navigationOptions: {
      headerVisible: true,
    },
  }
);

export default createAppContainer(MainNavigation);
```

[image: This is what I see]

Comment: Apparently, this is the expected behavior. https://github.com/react-navigation/react-navigation/issues/6149

Answer (score 0):

Can you try like the following?

eg:

```
 ...
    ...
        class MusicScreen extends Component {
          static navigationOptions = {
           title: 'MUSIICCCC',
           headerStyle: {
            backgroundColor: '#f4511e',
           },
           headerTintColor: '#fff',
           headerTitleStyle: {
            fontWeight: 'bold',
           },
         };
          render() {
            return (
                <View >
                    <Text>Music Screen</Text>
                </View>
            );
          }
        }
    ...
    ...


const MainNavigation = createBottomTabNavigator({
    Music : MusicScreen,
    Movies MoviesScreen,
  },
  {
    initialRouteName: 'Music',

  }
);

export default createAppContainer(MainNavigation);
```

Comment: Just tried. Doesn't work. Still can't see the headers.

Answer (score 0):

Try cleaning up your `createBottomTabNavigator` like so by removing any header data.

```
const MainNavigation = createBottomTabNavigator({
    Music : {screen: MusicScreen},
    Movies : {screen: MoviesScreen},
  }
);
```

Add `navigationOptions` to each screen individually.

```
class MusicScreen extends Component {

  static navigationOptions = {
    title: 'Musiiic',
  };

  render() {
    return (
        <View >
            <Text>Music Screen</Text>
        </View>
    );
  }
}

class MoviesScreen extends Component {

  static navigationOptions = {
    title: 'Movies',
  };

  render() {
    return (
    <View>
        <Text>Movies Screen</Text>
    </View>
    );
  }
}
```

Here are some docs [https://reactnavigation.org/docs/en/headers.html]

Comment: @user2101712 I've updated my answer. Please try and write back.

Answer (score 0):

Could you try this?

```js
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import { View, Text } from 'react-native';
import {  createAppContainer, createBottomTabNavigator } from 'react-navigation';

class MusicScreen extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
        <View >
            <Text>Music Screen</Text>
        </View>
    );
  }
}

class MoviesScreen extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
    <View>
        <Text>Movies Screen</Text>
    </View>
    );
  }
}

const MainNavigation = createBottomTabNavigator({
    Music : {
      screen: MusicScreen,
      navigationOptions: {
        title: "Music"
      }
    },
    Movies : {
      screen: MoviesScreen,
      navigationOptions: {
        title: 'Movies',
      },
    },
  },
  {
    headerMode: 'screen'
  }
);

export default createAppContainer(MainNavigation);
```